# What does an iOS Keystore contain and is that needed if I want to allow a fellow developer to try my app locally on his iOS device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application and my own developer account. I have another developer who is helping with this but he's mentioned that as he does not have a developer account he needs some file from me.

Can someone explain what I would need to give to another developer so that he could publish my app locally to his own phone?

Comment: developer accounts are free.  Why would he not have one?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the developer accounts were $99.  So just to confirm, there should be no need for me to give him my keystone information? Also if I did that, is that a risk for me?

Comment: You only need to pay if you want to submit to the app store.  If this guy is just testing for you, you can setup appcenter.ms to automatically build from your repo and release test builds he can download to his phone without needing to build himself.  If he does need to build himself, you will need to create a dev certificate for him and add him to a provisioning profile.  Both should be limited risk compared to his having access to your source code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is iOS test flight. You can add your app to App Store Connect and invite internal testers to test your beta builds. You can learn more [Here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). Hope it helps.

Comment: No I'm looking for a means for my other devs (not testers) to test the apps out every 30 minutes on their own personal phones after pulling the latest code changes from the repro.  Test flight is not a tool for that purpose.